# Py2neo (Neo4j) insert / create Relationships in bulk

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Trying to insert many new Relationship on existing nodes.
Current code is taking too much time for millions of Relationship. Is there a way to optimise the same?

```
from py2neo import *

g = Graph()
nodes = NodeMatcher(g)

for persons in relation:
    person_a, person_b = persons

    a = nodes.match("person",name=person_a).first()
    b = nodes.match("person",name=person_b).first()

    ab = Relationship(a, 'KNOWS' b)
    ab['date'] = '01-01-1980'

    g.create(ab)
```

Now assume 2 things:

1. Relations are in millions
2. To process things faster, I have a pickle dump which consists of all the node details in `py2neo.data.Node` datatype so that we can skip the `nodes.match(...)` part.

Note: If there is any other way to create the complete graph faster in bulk mode (where I'm willing to create the entire graph from scratch if time taken by adding Relationships > time taken to create entire graph). Number of nodes are around 80K.

Answer (score 1):

Py2neo has a bulk API that you might find useful:
https://py2neo.org/2021.1/bulk/index.html

Comment: Have already tried this one, this is working fine (better than creating 1 relationship at a time) but it's still slow. For around 100K relationships it's taking approx 40 mins (in batches of 5000 each)

Answer (score 0):

I found the bulk API is quick if you do not use the `start_node_key` and `end_node_key` parameters and instead directly specify the `ID`.

Comment: To clarify, if we use only the Node `ID`  for creating the relationships, then it'll be faster? Do you have any benchmark comparison?

Comment: Since writing the reply above, I have abandoned using `py2neo`. I found it was better to output all my nodes and relationships to a csv, and write a bit of cypher script to manually upload everything. It's still a pain, but I found it was far more performant than passing through a python wrapper. I don't have benchmarks.